Naming XML file composed from Cppcheck
I would like to have each XML file name correspond to the respective file they are scanning, but so far, when I run Cppcheck, it outputs the results into one XML document for all source files we are checking.
I am running the command
./cppcheck --enable=all --xml-version=2 -v ../drivers/aac >> errorCheck.xml

which scans all of the files in /drivers/aac. How can I have the results of each source file be in its own XML file and how can I customize the name of those files?
For example, if Cppcheck is scanning /drivers/aac/test1.c, I would like the XML file name to be /drivers/aac/test1.xml and the same for the other source files in /drivers/aac/.
Is there a way I can automate the file naming instead of hardcoding / ... / ... / for each script?

You could run Cppcheck on each file separately. But that will not give you all findings or false positives (e.g. unused functions). To improve that, you could still run on all file but suppress all findings except for one file. And run that for each file. But I guess that will increase the overall runtime. Alternatively you could write a script that parses your errorCheck.xml and splits the findings into multiple files.

And instead of >> errorCheck.xml you should use the option --output-file="path/to/your/result.xml"
